# AD FS error about SSL

Tags: adfs2.0

Do you have any idea about this error"

"ID1059: Cannot authenticate the user because the URL scheme is not https and requireSsl is set to true in the configuration, therefore the authentication cookie will not be sent. Change the URL scheme to https or set requireSsl to false on the cookieHandler element in configuration."

I connect to ADFS with SSL url but I need more resource as I am not sure I did it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, either change your web.config entry to:

```
 <cookieHandler requireSsl=“false“/>
```

or run your site on SSL and access via `https://some site`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Web Project properties and then in the Project URL option, make sure that the URL starts with https and not http
eg: https://localhost:22415/